# Schematic Capture: Proteus ISIS Bulk Component Editing

Tags: pcb, schematics, proteus

Is there any way in Proteus 8 Professional ISIS schematic capture to bulk edit components?

I have a sheet full of 0805 decoupling capacitors which I would like to make 0402. I tried all of the commands I could think of, but it only ever edits the last part selected. Selecting more than one part and then pressing `CTRL+E` doesn't do anything. This is possible to do in OrCAD and is very useful for updating footprints, MPNs, etc.

I tried opening the pdsprj file, and updating the {PACKAGE=...} parameters, but then it crashes when loading the file (suspect the text editor breaks the binary file).

Any advice is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another year has passed since posting this question, and I believe I have a satisfactory answer. The answer is in two parts:

1. Use `Tools > Search & Tag` to select the parts to apply the changes to.
2. Use `Tools > Property Assignment Tool` to make the changes to selected parts from step #1.

### An example

As an example, I will change all of the capacitor sizes from 0805 to 0603.

Select `Tools > Search & Tag` from the menu. Select `PACKAGE` from the property box (or whatever else you'd like to search on). Then enter the property value you'd like to search for. Here, I'm looking for "0805_CAP" but it could be whatever you need. Then press `Search` to perform the search. You'll see something similar to below. Make sure you see the parts you wish to replace have been selected:

[image: Proteus Search and Tag dialogue window]

Press `Done` when finished and you'll notice that all the parts listed are now selected:

[image: Example schematic showing selected parts]

With the parts selected, select `Tools > Property Assignment Tool` and then in the string field, enter the new property you wish to assign. In my case, that is "PACKAGE=0603_CAP". You have the option to do only the local page, or all (global) pages.

There are several other options, such as clicking on parts to assign properties, etc., which you can experiment with.

[image: Proteus Property Assignment Tool]

I chose global tagged (all sheets in design, all the selected parts) and pressed `Ok`. It took about 5 seconds on my 7 sheet design.

Hopefully that's useful to others, too!